# floated element clipped by absolute position div

Tags: html, css

I have a left sidebar `<header>` that is clipping the content to the right, which I am trying to unclip and move outward to the right. This is part of an html/css school assignment, so the left sidebar has to be positioned absolute. As per the assignment instructions, I am supposed to:

> "float the main section
>   on the left margin once the left margin has been clear of previously floated objects"

I did `clear:both` for this but it seems to have no effect. I know of clearfix, but I don't think that is appropriate for this.

The code JS Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/bsapaka/387Qp/

and on a temp site:

http://examplesite.comeze.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if you just remove `margin: 15px` from the `#main section` it will look fine.
This margin:15px is overwriting your `margin-left: 21%` and your `margin-top: 20px`

I suggest using google chromes Inspect Element to see what styles are taking precedence in your document as you are beginning web development. 
You can follow this google tutorial to figure out exactly how to use these Dev Tools.
[Learn Dev Tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/)